# Changing Webcam Feed from EpocCam to Built-In Webcam

Tags: webcam

I am trying to run a program that accesses my webcam camera. I have used Epoccam before then I deleted it. However, while using the program it tries to access Epoccam camera instead of taking the webcam feed from built-in webcam. How can I change/select the configurations of webcam feed ? I tried to reset SMC, to make my default webcam as built-in webcam but it didn't worked.

[image: error I get when I disable the access of application to camera from system preferences. It says cannot use EpocCam, but EpocCam is deleted ?]
[image: waiting view of epoccam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.kinoni.com/support-and-instructions/#Uninstallation for details on how to uninstall EpocCam.

> Run provided uninstall script from Terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/EpocCamPlugIn.plugin/Contents/Resources/uninst.sh
> ```
>
> If the script does not work you can also type the following commands
> in Terminal:
>
> ```
> launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.kinoni.epoccam.daemon.plist
> sudo launchctl stop com.kinoni.epoccam.daemon 
> sudo launchctl remove com.kinoni.epoccam.daemon
> sudo rm -r /Library/LaunchAgents/com.kinoni.epoccam.daemon.plist
> sudo rm -r /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/VirtualMic.driver
> sudo rm -r /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/EpocCamPlugin.plugin
> ```

Comment: it worked well ! easier than I expected, ı guess ı was mistaken by thinking that moving an application to thrash is enough. thanks for your help !